# Initialize a service inside custom adapter class

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-intentservice

I have a list view fragment which is filled with data from an array adapter. Each item of the list view contain a button. I want to do it such that when you press the button a service is initialized. I have implemented a Receiver class  and its on receive method inside the CustomAdaptor class,

```
public class LikeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String result=intent.getExtras().getString("result");
        Toast t3 = Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t3.show();
    }
```

I have implemented the following Service Class

```
public class LikeService  extends IntentService {

public LikeService() {
    super("Like");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=EUR&symbols="+"USD")
            .build();

    Response response = null;

    try {

        response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

        String code=intent.getAction();

        double ratio = json.getJSONObject("rates").getDouble(code);

        Intent i = new Intent("Like");
        i.putExtra("result", ratio);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(i);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

  }
```

The following method is located in the Adapter class and is supposed to initialize the service

```
public void askLikes()  {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, LikeService.class);
    String postid=Integer.toString(id);

    context.startService(i);
}
```

The on Click listener of the button which is defined in the getView method of the Adapter is the following:

```
    like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            askLikes();

            LikeReceiver receiver = new LikeReceiver();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("Like");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        }
    });
```

The problem is that when I press the button the toast doesnt show

Comment: is service starting. Can you put logs there and test if it prints out.

Comment: I suspect it doesn't because the log doesnt show anything.

Comment: I thought maybe it is not possible to initialize services inside adapter class

Comment: Yes, you can initialize service inside any class,l you just need context.

Comment: Check if service is registered in manifest